# рабочий цикл Vompal Wabbit

Tags: java, машинное-обучение

Хотелось бы узнать, какие есть практики использование программы vompal wabbit (можно и похожие, здесь это не важно).

1. Собираются данные
2. Тренируется модель
3. ?
4. profit

Не понятно, как использовать полученную модель в рабочем окружении.

После некоторых поисков, нашел следующие возможные варианты:

1. Запуск процесса vompal в интерактивном режиме из java приложения с указанием полученной модели
2. Запуск в режиме демона и взаимодействие через сокеты.

Первый вариант не уверен, что безопасен с точки зрения многопоточности.
Второй же имеет ряд нюансов. При отправке данных нужно какое то нефиксированное время ждать (какое?) результатов выполнения, после получения данных не известно стоит ли ждать новой порции данных или это все. т.к. данные это строка и из ее формата невозможно понять где завершать чтение.

Может быть есть какие то еще решения, более устойчивые и производительные?